# Keyframing from properties panel and from 3d viewport creates different entry on Graph Editor

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I have Bone.001 Armature selected, and I want rotate it and set a keyframe.

If I try to set the keyframe by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering my mouse pointer over the rotation properties on the properties panel, the following entry is created in the Graph Editor, (the rotation turns yellow when the keyframe is set)

[image]
[image]

But if I try to set the keyframe by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> when the mouse pointer is on the 3d viewport and selecting Rotation from the context menu, I get a different entry in the graph editor,
[image]
[image]

Notice that in the first one, the keyframes are enlisted under "ArmatureAction" and in the second one, the keyframes are enlisted under "ArmatureAction > Bone.001". The second one makes sense to me because I am recording the transformation of Bone.001 so the transformations should be enlisted under the name of the object.

Question is, what's the usefulness of first approach?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the former being a deviation from the latter, the latter seems like an automation implemented for convenience reasons.

Channel groups can be created manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. When inserting a Keyframe on a property in the UI rather than with <kbd>I</kbd> in the 3D View, in my experience it's usually something miscellaneous like render settings.

[image: 1]

The *Samples* and *Preview Samples* properties have only one instance per Scene, and the Scene already has an all-encompassing group element in the form of *SceneAction*.

Comment: I don't understand what your statement with `Channel groups` means in this context? Do you mean grouping transformation?

Comment: The channels here are "X Euler Rotation", "Y Euler Rotation", "Z Euler Rotation", etc. Channel groups are just collapsible groups created in the Graph Editor, or any editor that lets you view animation data Actions such as SceneAction, CubeAction, and SphereAction. They're created automatically when inserting Keyframes on a set of related transformation properties like "Euler Rotation" which, as viewed from the Properties panel, has 3 values (XYZ) and could easily clutter the UI if left un-grouped when animating alongside other sets of transformation properties such as Location and Scaling.

Comment: Got it. So, the question is - when someone is setting a keyframe on any or the transform property of an object, the keyframe should be under the object name. Allowing it to on the graph editor without the name of the object is definitely a problem. Yesterday, I've spend long hours trying to fix an animation problem on my game only to discover that the animation was exported incorrectly from blender.